# ASP.NET WebHelpers Library, Chart

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

So basically I wanted to use the chart from the webhelpers library I'm working on Visual Studio Webforms(aspx).
The idea was I click the button and then the chart appears (don't mind the other buttons and textboxes, they were from another test I was doing before. I'm new to aspx). But when I click the button, the whole page get "eaten" by the chart. The buttons disappear and the only thing that stays is the chart. Any ideas why this is happening?

1st page html code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div>Pagina 1</div>
        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_nome" runat="server" Text="Nome"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBx_nome" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_apelido" runat="server" Text="Apelido"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBx_apelido" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Btn_enviar" runat="server" Text="Enviar" OnClick="Btn_enviar_Click" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show chart" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

1st page aspx.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;



namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            { 

            }
            else {

            }



        }

        protected void Btn_enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx?apelido=" + TxtBx_apelido.Text + "&nome=" + TxtBx_nome.Text + "");
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Response.Redirect("WebFormChart.aspx");          //Faz redirect para a pagina     diferença?
            //Server.Transfer("WebFormChart.aspx");           //Faz redirect para a pagina      diferença?
              Server.Execute("WebFormChart.aspx");           //Faz include do conteodo da pagina
            //Response.WriteFile("WebFormChart.aspx");      //Escreve a pagina
        }


    }
}
```

.

2nd page html code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebFormChart.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebFormChart" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        This text wont show idk why
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

2nd page aspx.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Helpers;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebFormChart : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400, theme: ChartTheme.Vanilla3D)
                   .AddTitle("Title")
                   .AddSeries(chartType: "pie",
                       xValue: new[] { "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5" },
                       yValues: new[] { "4", "6", "4", "5", "7" });
            myChart.Write();

        }
    }
}
```

The result of this is:

[Page 1 with the button for showing the chart hightlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIZEv.png)

[Page 2 with the chart as you can see the text i had put there is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrszF.png)

Sorry for possibly bad English.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to everyone that helped (nobody),

I found a solution just in case someone finds this post and has the same problem, first i made an image in the 2nd page html code,

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    This text wont show idk why
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <div><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="600px" Width="600px" /></div>

</form>
```

Then in the 2nd page aspx.cs code I turned the chart into a WebImage and saved it to a folder then changed the image I created in the 2nd page html code .filepath to the folder with the chart, note you cant save the chart by simpli doing mychart.save I dont know why but it keep sending me an erro of accec denyed when it has accese (I use the same folder for the webimage so I dont know why that error used to show up).anyway here's the code for the 2nd page aspx.cs:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebFormChart : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {




        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400, theme: ChartTheme.Vanilla3D)
                   .AddTitle("Title")
                   .AddSeries(chartType: "pie",
                       xValue: new[] { "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5" },
                       yValues: new[] { "4", "6", "4", "5", "7" });
            myChart.ToWebImage().Save(@"Chart\chart", "jpeg", true);
            Image1.ImageUrl = @"Chart\chart.jpeg";

        }

    }
}
```

with this when even I click on the button1 it saves a jpeg file with the chart in the path "Chart\chart.jpeg" then it uses that path to show the image.

Once again thank you to everyone that helped me especially the one who downvoted,(someone upvoted so its at 0 now).